# Index notation: associative property

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors, differential-operators, index-notation

I have given the following term, that I can write in index notation as following:
$$ (\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{b} = a_j \partial_j b_i$$
Now I can exchange the order and get 
$$ \partial_j b_i a_j = (\partial_j b_i) a_j $$
which equals to 
$$ (\partial_j b_i) a_j = (\nabla \mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{a}$$
Is this enough to show that 
$$ (\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{b} = (\nabla \mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{a}$$?

Comment: Are you sure the equation $((\nabla b)\cdot a)_i = \partial_jb_ia_j$ is correct?

Comment: The part in the brackets is a matrix times the vector a...is there an error? I am not sure, as I am really new to indexnotation, so I would appreciate your help...

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: what definition of $(\nabla b)\cdot a$ are you using? If you define it as contraction on the first index of $\nabla b$ then your equation is correct, but if I recall correctly some people define it as contraction on the second index. Are you following a particular source? or did you come up with that notation on your own?

Comment: this is my source i used: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pmvs/courses/mcl702/notation.pdf

Comment: See part 7. f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 7. f) of your source there is a remark noting that $B\cdot a \neq a\cdot B$, when $B$ is a 2-tensor.

This is because $a\cdot B$ is the contraction of $a$ with the *first* index of $B$, while $B\cdot a$ is to be interpreted as contraction of $a$ with the *second* index of $B$.

Hence in the present case we have
$$(\nabla b \cdot a)_i = (\nabla b)_{ij}a_j = \partial_ib_ja_j$$
c.f. with your equation $(\nabla b\cdot a)_i=\partial_jb_ia_j$, which should actually be $(a\cdot\nabla b)_i=a_j\partial_jb_i=\partial_jb_ia_j$.

Thus, the identity you actually derived is
$$(a\cdot \nabla)b = a\cdot (\nabla b)$$

Comment: Thank you! But if I now assume a and b to be column vectors, the first case of $B\cdot a$ would apply, right?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase your question please? What about rows or columns? I wasn't thinking about a particular way to array the entries.

Comment: I was just thinking, if I assume the vectors to be column vectors with dimension (3x1) (as given in many problems, in my case an acoustic problem), only $B\cdot a$ would work out as dim(B) = (3x3) and dim(a) = (3x1) or am I wrong?

Comment: You can think of index notation as independent of matrix notation. If $B$ and $a$ are the tuples of components, denote by $[B]$ and $[a]$ their respective matrices. If $[a]$ is a column, then both the column $[B][a]$ and the row $[a]^T[B]^T$ have as entries the components of $B\cdot a$, while the components of $a\cdot B$ are both in the row $[a]^T[B]$ and in the column $[B]^T[a]$.

Comment: Similarly, if $[a]$ is a row, then both the column $[B][a]^T$ and the row $[a][B]^T$ have as entries the components of $B\cdot a$, while the components of $a\cdot B$ are both in the row $[a][B]$ and in the column $[B]^T[a]^T$. Does that help? What I mean is that the components don't care whether you arrange them in rows or columns.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot for your explanation! I study electrical engineering and we never used index-notation, this helped a lot!